# TypeScript cast (assertion) results in Syntax Error compiler warning?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I've got a TypeScript script that has to interact with a third-party vendor that uses global functions as callbacks (you can't pass in a callback). For instance, to "listen" for a result from their "API", you define the function SetElqContent.  E.g.,

```
window.SetElqContent = function(){/* handle result */};
```

When the TypeScript compiler sees this line, it complains that `The property 'SetElqContent' does not exist on value of type 'Window'`.

I thought I could get around this by simply casting to type "any". Actually, this isn't type casting but [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf#page=70), but I think of it as casting, although I understand it's [not quite the same](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/479411). So, I tried:

```
(<any>window).SetElqContent = function(){/* handle result */};;
```

To m y surprise, this results in `Syntax error`, and the line number and column points to the `<` character in the `<any>` cast. I tried a few other variants, and I get `Syntax error` on the initial `<` of the cast no matter what kind of cast I was doing:

```
var windowAny = <any>window;
var docElement = <HTMLElement>window.document;
```

What is it about my type assertions that is invalid syntax?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2, which has a "compile on save" feature for TypeScript files. That's how I'm compiling my .ts files, and it's from in Visual Studio where the `Syntax error` message is emitted.

UPDATE: Apparently this is related to Visual Studio. When I use the standalone tsc compiler to compile the same file, it emits no errors or warnings.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded, you provided some helpful insights. I upvoted all answers. I think this is a Visual Studio issue--and apparently it only manifest in certain situations. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently my syntax is correct but there is a bug in the Visual Studio tooling. I can't provide exact reproduce steps, and in fact, deleting everything in the .ts file, saving, then restoring the code (via ctrl-z) and resaving caused the "syntax error" warning to disappear.

If I can determine any more specifics about what causes this issue to manifest, I'll report back.

Comment: JFYI, I've run into a number of other situations where the Visual Studio TypeScript tooling is reporting a `syntax error`, `Expected ')'`, or `Expected ';'`. In every instance, command-line compilation of the same file(s) with tsc results in no errors or warnings. I can't figure out a rhyme or reason, but it certainly does appear that there are bugs in the Visual Studio tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to create a type definitions file for it
If the library name is eloqua.js, you create a eloqua.d.ts file and refer to it in your .js file like

> /// < reference path="../typings/eloqua.d.ts" />

There are many type definition files online available at definitelyTyped website.
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

You can contribute yours to there as well.

Comment: if it uses Module pattern, and don't want to create type definitions for it to refer in your typescript, you can import the module
`import window.SetElqContent = require("eloqua");`

Comment: I'll try and put something together. There is basically no documentation for this "library," but having a TypeScript definition file that is well comment would have helped me tremendously. Maybe I can save someone else the headaches I experienced.

Answer (score 1):

If you extend the `Window` interface definition, you'll remove the error:

```
interface Window {
    SetElqContent: Function;
}

window.SetElqContent = function(){/* handle result */};
```

Comment: This is helpful and I think I will move this direction, but I'd still like to know why Visual Studio doesn't like the type assertion syntax. As noted in my question update, this warning is only emitted from within Visual Studio, when it autocompiles a .ts on save. Executing `tsc` from the command line, compiling the exact same file, results in no errors on warnings.

Comment: In your question, you set `window.SetElqContent = SetElqContent` - I assume you mean to have a function in that second `SetElqContent` position. Interestingly, if you just create a function in the global scope called `SetElqContent` this may suffice (i.e. don't even bother with the `window.` in the first place: this depends on how the library calls it.

Comment: SetElqContent is a locally scoped function in my code, but I realize that wasn't clear in my question. I updated it to use only anonymous functions.

Comment: If you're inside a function, and that function is inside a RequireJS module, can you "create a function in the global scope?" If so, how? I didn't know this was possible. In my case, I'm using RequireJS and I'm trying to to use this library inside a module.

Comment: Functions are scoped to the function they are declared within, so you need to explicitly use `window.` if you are within a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do the assertion properly:

```
function SetElqContent(){/* handle result */};

// FINE
(<any>window).SetElqContent = SetElqContent;
```

or

```
// FINE
(<any>window).SetElqContent = function SetElqContent(){/* handle result */};
```

However you *should* avoid *asserting* and just do what Steve Fenton recommends as it is more *discoverable*

**Update**
Demo in VS: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this appears to be the same syntax that I'm already using. It does give me some confidence that I'm using the correct syntax for type assertions, though. At this point I'm thinking it's a problem with the Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: In the first case....th error is not because of assertion....it's because you probably haven't declared the function correctly. The RHS of the equation

Comment: I don't think so. Remember, cli tsc compile works fine. Also, i get this anytime i use type assertion.

Comment: I did try a copy paste of your examples. Same warning about syntax.

Comment: @Josh they work fine in the TypeScript playground. Note : Resharper has known TypeScript parsing problems. If you disable resharper and retry you should definitely not get any errors

Comment: I don't have resharper. Maybe a bug in the Visual Studio TypeScript tooling?

Comment: Ahhhh...which version of TS tooling are you on? Search typeScript in control panel programs and  features

Comment: "typescript" does not appear in my "Programs and Features" list in Control Panel. I am running the Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 (Build 2014), which you can read about here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-may-12-vs. It says "With the release of Update 2, we’re shipping many new features for web developers, including TypeScript 1.0 RTM." My CLI tsc is version 1.0.1.0, but I don't think Visual Studio uses that.

Comment: That is the message. There is nothing else. It's also the only warning or error for this TypeScript file. Here's a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/HW35Cql7Yhu. If I right click and say "copy", here's what I get in the clipboard: `Warning Syntax error {project-path}\Secure\profile\app\viewmodels\email.ts 45 14 Secure`. "Secure" is the root folder of the project. Line 45 column 14 is the location of the `<` in the type assertion.

Comment: Ooooh kay... so I just highlighted everything in the file, hit backspace (deleted everything), saved the file, and error went away (as you'd expect). I then hit ctrl-z to undo deleting everything, saved... and the "syntax error" warning did not return. Makes no sense! It's the *exact* same code!